# NSTextField created from custom class appears randomly

Tags: swift, subclass, nsview, nstextfield, nsbutton

I have a main NSView with 2 NSView subviews containing each a custom NSButton (all created in Interface Builder). My custom button class is programmatically creating an NSTextField below the buttons, by adding it from the superview:
[image]

And the custom NSButton class code:

```
class buttonUpDown: NSButton {
    var myLabel:NSTextField!
    
    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        let labelWidth=CGFloat(90)

        print("init")
        superview?.autoresizesSubviews = false
        myLabel = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(frame.origin.x+frame.size.width/2-labelWidth/2,frame.origin.y-20,labelWidth,16))
        
        myLabel?.stringValue = "Mesh Quality"
        myLabel.alignment = .center
        myLabel.font? = .systemFont(ofSize: 8)

        myLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        myLabel.isBordered = false
        myLabel.isEditable = false

        superview!.addSubview(myLabel)
    }
}
```

When I have a single Button referencing the class, the label appears properly.
[image]

But when I have 2, only 1 label is appearing randomly left or right:
[image]

What do I miss to have a text displayed below each button ?

Comment: Have you tried "Capture View Hierarchy" to inspect the view?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that functionality ! Seems I found the issue. Creating a label in the init function will give erratic positioning of the view frame. Adding them from the draw func, makes it better consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Creating a label in the init function will give erratic positioning of the view frame. Adding them from the draw func, makes it more reliable.

Comment: Please do not do this in drawRect. Use viewDidAppear instead